# Laravel4 Get 10 items with highest count of a relation type

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Assume my project contains `Post`s which have many `Vote`s.

How can I get the 10 `Post`s which have the highest count of votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this (AFAIK) in one nice query with Eloquent. You can either use DB::select() using the table names directly and joining and ordering by the count.

However, if you don't mind a bit of overhead and PHP processing you can do something like the following:

```
$posts = Post::with('Vote')->all()->sortBy(function ($item) {
    return $item->votes->count();
}, SORT_REGULAR, true)->take(10);
```

Comment: No problem - I should probably have caveated this a bit more than I have though - Bradley's version, while more low-level, is far better as it uses MySQL to do all the heavy lifting. My way here gets all posts and all votes from the DB, uses PHP to get the counts and order by them, and then limits in memory to 10. So while looking nice, it probably wouldn't be wise to use with >1k posts each with >5k votes, for example. You can make this better, but you'll still have performance issues eventually.

Comment: Performance will not be an issue I guess. There will be max. 100 posts with max. 500 votes on the highest. (if not far less)

Comment: @Strernd my method does it in one query.

Comment: `->with('Vote')` gave man an error. It seems to work without that part.

Comment: Ahh sorry, that may be `->with('votes')`. All that does is kinda helps the performance a little by preloading the votes. But yeah, it can be used without, though I would change the anonymous function body in that case to `return $item->votes()->count();` so that no memory is wastes storing all the votes when only the count is required.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do some manual database query using DB::raw on the select.

```
$modela = new ModelA;
$modelb = new ModelB;

$tablea = $modela->getTable();
$tableb = $modelb->getTable();

$query = $modela->query();
$query->select(DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$tableb} as b where b.a_id = {$tablea}.id) AS b_count"));
```

Untested but the query should be correct. You will need to update WHERE b.a_id to the related field name of course.

Comment: Sorry Bradley, I edited the question to clarify the models a bit. It made your answer look a bit odd so I updated it to follow the same conventions.

Comment: I say I edited it - I attempted to edit it, but it seems my edit got rejected. Sorry anyway.